# Consistency of an intersection property

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

If $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal then we denote by  $[\kappa]^\kappa$ the collection of subsets of $\kappa$ that have cardinality $\kappa$. We say that $\kappa$ is *intersectionally strange* if there is a cardinal $\lambda \in \kappa$ such that:

> there is ${\cal A}\subseteq [\kappa]^\kappa$ with $|{\cal A}| >\kappa$, and  $|X\cap Y|<\lambda$ for all $X\neq Y\in {\cal A}$.

Is it consistent that for every infinite cardinal $\kappa$ there is an intersectionally strange cardinal $\alpha$ with $\alpha >  \kappa$?

Comment: Yes. This was studied extensively by Baumgartner (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484376900188)